# Implementing a like button in AJAX output?

Tags: ajax, facebook-like

I've put this after my body tag in my index page:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

and the rest of the SDK code..

I'm loading images via ajax popup, and I'm trying to load a like button for each of them too, but it doesn't load.

Why is this? How can I make like button work on AJAX results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    FB.XFBML.parse(); 
    twttr.widgets.load();
    IN.parse(document);
```

This is how you refresh likes when they are appended via javascript.